# Считывание из файла c++

Tags: c++, строки, fstream

В текстовом файле имеется информация, представленная в таком формате

```
56;maz;valeriy
45;kamaz;maxim
344;bmw;vitua
```

Необходимо считать эти данные и поместить в вектор, помогите пожалуйста

```
vector <bus> inputVector(ifstream& in, vector <bus> VectFlow)
{
    bus tempbus;

    while (in >> tempbus.bsNumber)
    {  

        string tempStr;
        in >> tempbus.busName;
        in >>tempStr;
        tempbus.fbBus.clear();
        int i = 0; string temp;

        while (i != (tempStr.size() + 1))
        {
            temp = "";

            while (tempStr[i] != ' ' && tempStr[i])
            {
                temp += tempStr[i];
                i++;
            }
            tempbus.fbBus.push_back(temp);
            i++;
        }

        VectFlow.push_back(tempbus);
    }

    return VectFlow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Примерно так (не компилировал, просто набросок, чтобы показать идею. **Проверок на неверный ввод тоже нет!**).

```
void inputVector(ifstream& in, vector<bus>& VectFlow)
{
    bus tempbus;
    string s;
    while(getline(in,s))
    {
        tempbus.bsNumber = stoi(s);
        size_t pos1, pos2;
        pos1 = s.find(';');
        pos2 = s.find(';',pos1+1);
        tempbus.busName = s.substr(pos1+1,pos2-pos1-1);
        tempbus.fbBus = s.substr(pos2+1);
        VectFlow.push_back(tempbus);
    }
}
```